# How can I make the size of the Ticks consistent with the size of the figure?

Tags: plotting, frame

I wrote this code to help me manipulate the size of the figure along `x` and `y` (controlled by`XZ`,`YZ`) with possessing consistent `Ticks` but I left with one step which is to get rid of the green numbers without using `White` color. How can I do that?

```
TX[XZ_, YZ_] := Piecewise[{{XZ/YZ, XZ >= YZ}, {1, XZ < YZ}}]
s[j_, tl_] := Table[{j i, j i, {0, -tl}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}]; 
p[j_, ts_, ns_] := 
 Table[{(j (i))/ns, "", {0, -ts}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];(*ns>1*)
ticks[j_, tl_, ts_, ns_] := ArrayFlatten[{{s[j, tl]}, {p[j, ts, ns]}}];
Tx[MSx_, Msz_, Ssz_, nSS_, XZ_, YZ_] := 
  ticks[MSx, Msz TX[XZ, YZ] , Ssz TX[XZ, YZ] , nSS];
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"mysty", x_Real, y_Real, YZ_, 
   XZ_}, _] :=
  {AspectRatio -> 1, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
    FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] x]}], 
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]],  
     Green}, 
       {Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]], Green}}}

With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1}, 
 Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
  Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
  FrameTicks -> {Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ], 
    Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ]}, 
  PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003 , 0.003, YZ, XZ}, ImagePadding -> 80]]
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `Green` with `FontColor->White`?

Comment: @kglr, what is the difference if we replace Green with White?

Comment: HD2006, no difference in this case (because tick colors are set via `ticks` and the color directive in `FrameTicksStyle` affects only the label color). In general,  frame/ticks/labels can be styled independently of each other as in, e.g.,`Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> 20, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Purple, Brown}, {Yellow, Magenta}}, 
 FrameTicks -> All, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Blue}, {Red, 
    Directive[Green, FontColor -> Orange]}}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form `FrameTicks -> {{leftticks, Automatic}, {bottomticks, Automatic}}` to specify frame ticks:

```
With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1}, 
  Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], 
    ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ], Automatic},
        {Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ], Automatic}}, 
    PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003, 0.003, YZ, XZ}, ImagePadding -> 80]]
```

[image]

Comment: I really did that but I started with x-axis Ticks like this:  `FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sx, XZ, YZ],Automatic}, {Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sy, YZ, XZ], Automatic}}` but the style was destroyed. i just realize that Mathematica starts with y-axis  :-)

Comment: why  is it not working with `ListLinePlot` ? `data = Table[{z, Sin[z]}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1}];` `With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1}, 
 ListLinePlot[data, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ], 
     Automatic}, {Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ], Automatic}}, 
  PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003, 0.003, YZ, XZ}, ImagePadding -> 80]]`