# Why isn't FrameTicks working properly with ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I wrote this small code to get custom  `FrameTicks`

```
TX[XZ_, YZ_] := Piecewise[{{XZ/YZ, XZ >= YZ}, {1, XZ < YZ}}]
s[j_, tl_] := Table[{j i, j i, {0, -tl}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}]; 
p[j_, ts_, ns_] := 
 Table[{(j (i))/ns, "", {0, -ts}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];(*ns>1*)
ticks[j_, tl_, ts_, ns_] := ArrayFlatten[{{s[j, tl]}, {p[j, ts, ns]}}];
Tx[MSx_, Msz_, Ssz_, nSS_, XZ_, YZ_] := 
  ticks[MSx, Msz TX[XZ, YZ] , Ssz TX[XZ, YZ] , nSS];
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"mysty", x_Real, y_Real, YZ_, 
   XZ_}, _] :=
  {AspectRatio -> 1, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"},
    FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] x]}], 
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]],  
     Automatic}, 
       {Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]], Automatic}}}
```

Now I am using `FrameTicks`  which works fine with `Plot`

```
With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1}, 
  Plot[Sin[z], {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], 
    ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ], Automatic},
        {Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ], Automatic}}, 
    PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003, 0.003, YZ, XZ}, ImagePadding -> 80]]
```

[image]

Then, if I use `ListLinePlot` it is not working where the size of the `Ticks` on the `Top` and `Right` sides of the `Frame` is smaller

```
data = Table[{z, Sin[z]}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1}, 
 ListLinePlot[data, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red], ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ], 
     Automatic}, {Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ], Automatic}}, 
  PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003, 0.003, YZ, XZ}, ImagePadding -> 80]]
```

[image]

Comment: I see very faint green ticks. What kind of ticks are intended?

Comment: @SHuisman, the problem is with the size of the ticks not the color, I update the question and code.

Comment: Looks like `Plot` replaces the `Automatic` ticks with a version of your custom ticks with the labels removed, while `ListPlot` simply leaves the `Automatic` there, resulting the different ticks. You should be able to simply add a way to your `Tx` to generate the ticks without labels, and use that to manually generate the other frame sides.

Comment: @LukasLang, well at the beginning I did that  and the `Ticks` were Ok but could not get rid of the `Labels` on the `Top` and `Right` sides of the `Frame`. So, I used `Automatic` to get the size fixed and get red of the labels (kindly, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225875/how-can-i-make-the-size-of-the-ticks-consistent-with-the-size-of-the-figure). Now If I impose the size of the Ticks with `ListLinePlot` I will get the problem back with the `Labels` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on what I suggested in the comments:

```
TX[XZ_, YZ_] := Piecewise[{{XZ/YZ, XZ >= YZ}, {1, XZ < YZ}}]
s[lbls_, j_, tl_] := Table[{j i, If[lbls, j i, ""], {0, -tl}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];
p[j_, ts_, ns_] := Table[{(j (i))/ns, "", {0, -ts}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];(*ns>1*)ticks[lbls_, j_, tl_, ts_, ns_] := ArrayFlatten[{{s[lbls, j, tl]}, {p[j, ts, ns]}}];
Tx[lbls_ : True, MSx_, Msz_, Ssz_, nSS_, XZ_, YZ_] := ticks[lbls, MSx, Msz TX[XZ, YZ], Ssz TX[XZ, YZ], nSS];

System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme[{"mysty", x_Real, y_Real, YZ_, XZ_}, _] := {AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] x]}], Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]], Automatic}, {Directive[Black, Thickness[TX[YZ, XZ] y]], Automatic}}}

data = Table[{z, Sin[z]}, {z, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
With[{XZ = 400, YZ = 200, sx = 3, sy = 1},
 ListLinePlot[
  data,
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
  Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red],
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ},
  FrameTicks -> {
    {
     Tx[sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ],
     Tx[False, sy, 0.03, 0.015, 5 sy, YZ, XZ]
     }, {
     Tx[sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ],
     Tx[False, sx, 0.03, 0.015, 2 sx, XZ, YZ]
     }
    },
  PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.003, 0.003, YZ, XZ},
  ImagePadding -> 80
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

This works by adding an optional `lbls` parameter to the tick function that can be used to omit the labels from the generated ticks. This parameter is then simply set to `False` for the appropriate axes, leading to properly sized ticks.

Comment: I see how you do it, thanks to a lot!